# How to skip header in csv and parse the column?

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

```js
let csv = require('fast-csv');
let fs = require('fs');
let readFileStream = fs.createReadStream(csvPath).setEncoding('utf-8');
let insList = [];
csv
    .fromStream(readStream, {headers: true})
    .on('data', function (data) {
        if (data[1] !== '' && insList.indexOf(data[1]) === -1 )
            insList.push(data[1]);

    })
    .on('end', function () {
        console.log(insList);
        console.log('done');
    })
```

The `console.log(instList)` line gives `undefined` when the `{headers:true}` is passed as argument to `csv.fromStream`. Why does that happen and how can I solve it?

If `{headers:true}` is not passed as argument the `insList` array gives the column name and all other unique elements in that column.
I want the `insList` array to hold all unique items of column 1 (i.e. `data[1]`).

Answer (score 2):

##### Edit 31-May-2022:

Sample working code in [repl.it](https://replit.com/@VenkateshK/FastCSVDemo#index.js)

##### Before 31-May-2022(works for an older version of fast-csv)

I have found that it works fine. However, the only problem was that the data is an object not an array. I have tested with this csv.

```
title,count
a,1
b,2


c,3
d,4
```

The data was an object in format { title: 'a', count:'1'}.

```
const csv = require('fast-csv');
const fs = require('fs');

const readStream = fs.createReadStream('./test.csv').setEncoding('utf-8');
const insList = [];
csv
  .fromStream(readStream, { headers: true, ignoreEmpty: true })
  .on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('data === ', data);
    // major change is here
    if (data && data !== {}) insList.push(data);
    else console.log('empty data', data);
  })
  .on('end', function () {
    console.log('end => ', insList);
    console.log('done');
  })
```

Hope this helps

Comment: what do you mean data is an object? my data is a csv file.

Comment: @ann I meant that the 'data variable' in callback is an object